# How to place a container on top of other container properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I have a container with image and I wanted to place another small container on top to show an icon on the bottom right of it

```
   Widget buildImage2() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black12,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.photo),
                            title: const Text('Gallery'),
                            onTap: () {
                              pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                            title: const Text('Camera'),
                            onTap: () {
                              pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),

                        ],
                      );
                    });
              },

              child: Stack(

                clipBehavior: Clip.none,

                children: [
                  CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: imageURL,

                    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                      return Ink.image(
                        image: imageProvider,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,

                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                          width: 160.0,
                          height: 160.0,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  Container(

                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                    width: 150.0,
                    height: 150.0,

                    child: Positioned(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xFF5B84B1),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3)
                        ),
                        child: const Icon (Icons.camera_alt, size: 25,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ),

                ],
              ),


            ),


          ),
        ),
        // color: Colors.black12,
      ),

    );
  }
```

But its not giving me the exact behaviour I am looking for. the two containers are placed on top of each other but the small one with the icon is being cutted from the edges as the image shows:

[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you crop it in the parent or ancestor of the `Stack`?

Comment: No, I didnt and I actually updated the quistion to include the full widget code

Answer (score 1):

You can use of `Stack()` with `Positioned(bottom:0.0, right: 0.0, child: Icon()`

You can try to put another container outside of Clipped Container in stack.

```
  Stack(
      children: [
          Container(
            height: 100.0.h,
            width: 100.0.h,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                       image: AssetImage(AppImages.placeHolderImage))
                  ),
                ),
            Positioned(
               bottom: 0.0,
               right: 2.0,
               child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0.sp),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                         shape: BoxShape.circle,
                         color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                child: Image.asset(
                     AppImages.cameraProfile,
                     scale: 3.0.sp,
                ),),)
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

camera Icon from this Container gesture you need add this line `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent`

like this

```
GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, // add this line
      onTap: () {
        //TODO
      },
      child: Container(

        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
        width: 150.0,
        height: 150.0,

        child: Positioned(
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xFF5B84B1),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3)
            ),
            child: const Icon (Icons.camera_alt, size: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons. Nothing has been changed actually

Comment: okay, if you want profile pic clickable just add this line in gesture " behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent"

Comment: I dont have a problem with the profile pic being clickable as i am wraping the whole thing in an inkWell and you can look at the code again as I have updated my question to include the full code. My problem is just that the icon container is not appearing properly and its being cutted from the bottom right edges

Comment: okay got it. i'll share new code

Comment: try this padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),

Comment: well this actually just drag it inside the container but it doesnt solve that issue, however, I have actually managed to solve it differently and I will be posting my answer so you can have a look. And thanks again for your response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments.
This is how I solved that issue:

```
Widget buildImage() {
    return Center(
      child: Container(

        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black12,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),

        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.photo),
                          title: const Text('Gallery'),
                          onTap: () {
                            pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                          title: const Text('Camera'),
                          onTap: () {
                            pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),

                      ],
                    );
                  });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                      imageURL
                 )

                ),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,

              ),


              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
              width: 150.0,
              height: 150.0,
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(

                    color: const Color(0xFF5B84B1),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3)
                ),
                child: const Icon (Icons.camera_alt, size: 25,
                ),
              ),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Stack Widget and set the property

> clipBehavior: Clip.none,
> to full control for Positioned Widget
> . See the below example for reference

```
              Stack(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 150.0,
                        width: 150.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          size: 70,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0.0,
                        right: 6.0,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white54,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what I have in the question. I was using Stack with clipBehavior: Clip.none, but it was not solving the issue I mentioned. Anyway I have managed to solve it differently as I shared my solution as well as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need overlay like me please follow this

[image]

```
Container(
      decoration: iconStyle(context),
      child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 23,
                  height: 23,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 7, 8, 7),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  child: assetImage(context, "bell.png"),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -5,
                  right: -5,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 12,
                    height: 12,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Tingsapp.white, 
                      width: 2)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
      );
```